# Hosted SQL Server, use Windows scheduled tasks

Tags: sql-server, scheduled-tasks

I have a service that is running on SQL Server 2008 with no jobs feature and I want to be able to have scheduled tasks for executing stored procedures. Is there any way to do this using with does task scheduler? Server is hosted off-site and not on my network and I do have read/write access to SQL Server.

Comment: You need to talk to the hosting company - it's totally up to them whether they give you the ability to schedule Windows tasks (or not). And also whether you can create SQL Server agent jobs depends again on what they provide and if your hosting plan includes this ability. This is not something we can answer from a technical perspective ....

Comment: It's not clear exactly what this service is. You can certainly use windows scheduler to execute T-SQL. You just use it to run `SQLCMD.EXE`. But it's not clear if this is an option for you

Comment: There are also scheduler type services in Azure, AWS that might hep.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  The hosted vendor has just told me that the version of SQL they run on their servers don't include the SQL Agent.  I can run these stored procedures within the SQL Management Studio without a problem so I am assuming I can do it through a Windows Task Scheduler if a connection to the SQL server can be made.